# google cloud shell not able to get maven dependency for spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, google-secret-manager

I am trying to add [secrets](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/secret-management) to spring boot [app](https://%20https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic).

so added to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven version is

```
xyz_pqr@cloudshell:~/projects/spring-petclinic (xyzprj)$ ./mvnw --version
Apache Maven 3.8.2 (ea98e05a04480131370aa0c110b8c54cf726c06f) Maven home:
/home/xyz_pqr/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.2-bin/1um3pu5poco57pibs3g92d6vrf/apache-maven-3.8.2
Java version: 17.0.4, vendor: Debian, runtime:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64 Default locale: en_US, platform
encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968 OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.65+", arch:
"amd64", family: "unix" xyz_pqr@cloudshell:~/projects/spring-petclinic
(xyzprj)$
```

It gives the issue

Failed to execute goal on project spring-petclinic: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.samples:spring-petclinic:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:jar:3.4.0 in spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot)

The complete error is

> [INFO] ------------< org.springframework.samples:spring-petclinic
>
> > ------------ [INFO] Building petclinic 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------- Downloading from spring-snapshots:
> > https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager/3.4.0/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager-3.4.0.pom
> > Downloading from spring-milestones:
> > https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager/3.4.0/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager-3.4.0.pom
> > Downloading from central:
> > https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager/3.4.0/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager-3.4.0.pom
> > [WARNING] The POM for
> > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:jar:3.4.0
> > is missing, no dependency information available Downloading from
> > spring-snapshots:
> > https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager/3.4.0/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager-3.4.0.jar
> > Downloading from spring-milestones:
> > https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager/3.4.0/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager-3.4.0.jar
> > Downloading from central:
> > https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager/3.4.0/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager-3.4.0.jar
> > [INFO]
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  3.274 s [INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-14T23:34:50Z
> > [INFO]
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-petclinic: Could not
> > resolve dependencies for project
> > org.springframework.samples:spring-petclinic:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could
> > not find artifact
> > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:jar:3.4.0
> > in spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot) -> [Help 1]
> > [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
> > Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
> > enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
> > the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> > [ERROR] [Help 1]
> > http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
> > xyz_pqr@cloudshell:~/projects/spring-petclinic (xyzprj)$

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cloud-gcp-secret-manager
 has same issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with document at [Secret Management](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/secret-management)

it says

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

so replace *org.springframework.cloud* with **com.google.cloud**

[image]